# Will actionlib.SimpleActionClient.cancel_all_goals block until completion?

Tags: ros, rospy

Suppose I have the following:

```python
action_client.cancel_all_goals()
print(action_client.get_status() != 'ACTIVE')
```

Is the above guaranteed to print `True` every time?

In other words, does `SimpleActionClient.cancel_all_goals()` cancel all goals before returning, or does it just send instructions to
cancel goals without waiting for the goals to be really cancelled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action_client.cancel_all_goals()` **just sends an instruction to cancel goals without waiting**.

Since the documentation of the method is not very helpful you need to have a look to [action_client.h](https://github.com/ros/actionlib/blob/indigo-devel/include/actionlib/client/action_client.h#L135) or [action_client.py](https://github.com/ros/actionlib/blob/indigo-devel/src/actionlib/action_client.py#L559) to find out whats happening.

The code shows that to cancel all goals only a simple message is published (`self.pub_cancel.publish(cancel_msg)` or `self.pub_cancel.publish(cancel_msg)`). This means the call is asynchronous and will not block.

This means your code

```python
action_client.cancel_all_goals()
print(action_client.get_status() != 'ACTIVE')
```

will typically print `False` but this is **not guaranteed** because:

- The client could be already `PREEMPTED`, `ABORTED`, ... before
- ROS is not deterministic, this means in theory the client *could* be cancelled between the calls of `cancel_all_goals` and `get_status` due to a thread switch.